# Django - Check if form submit button was clicked?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, form-submit

How can I specifically check if the submit button of my form was clicked?

The if `form.is_valid()` validation does that check but also returns True without clicking the button (When the clean() method was executed). How can I set a variable to True when the submit button was clicked. I try to confirm a upload and when the user clicks the submit button it should execute a Database Query.

Here is my `views.py`

```
def file_upload(request):
    save = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = ConfirmationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if cache.get('save'):
            print("True")
            save = True
        else:
            print("False")
            save = False
        print("request.POST: ", request.POST)
        print("request.FILES: ", request.FILES)
        print("save: ", save)
        print("form: ", form)
        print("form2: ", form2)
        if not request.FILES:
            print("empty")
        else:
            print("not empty")
        updated_obj = 0
        created_obj = 0
        duplicate_obj = 0
        count = 0
        # Prüfen ob CSV Datei valide ist (keine doppelten Datensätze)
        rs1 = list()
        rs2 = list()
        d_list1 = list()
        d_list2 = list()
        csv_file = get_data(request, save)
        csv_file.seek(0)
        file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                row_set1 = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
                row_set2 = [row[5], row[6]]
                if row_set1 not in rs1:
                    rs1.append(row_set1)
                else:
                    d_list1.append(row_set1)
                if row_set2 not in rs2:
                    rs2.append(row_set2)
                else:
                    d_list2.append(row_set2)
            except IndexError:
                break
        if len(d_list1) and len(d_list2):
            messages.error(request, "In der CSV Datei sind folgende Datensätze mehrfach vorhanden")
            messages.error(request, "Dosen: %s " % d_list1)
            messages.error(request, "Ports: %s " % d_list2)
            return redirect('appp:index')
        elif len(d_list1) and not len(d_list2):
            messages.error(request, "In der ausgewählten CSV Datei sind folgende Dosen mehrfach vorhanden")
            messages.error(request, "%s " % d_list1)
            return redirect('appp:index')
        elif not len(d_list1) and len(d_list2):
            messages.error(request, "In der ausgewählten CSV Datei sind folgende Ports mehrfach vorhanden")
            messages.error(request, "%s " % d_list2)
            return redirect('appp:index')
        # Wenn CSV Datei valide ist --> Datei hochladen
        updated_list = list()
        created_list = list()
        csv_file.seek(0)
        file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        print("reader: ", reader)
        for row in reader:
            count += 1
            try:
                datet = datetime.now().date()
                datum = datet.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
                row[7] = datum
                row[8] = str(request.user)
                dataset1 = CSV5.objects.filter(gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                 gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                 raum=row[3], dose=row[4])#.values_list("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer",
                                                 #                                       "ebene", "raum", "dose")
                dataset2 = CSV5.objects.filter(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6])#.values_list("switch_ip", "switch_port")
                #ds1 = CSV5.objects.values_list("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer", "ebene",
                                                                  #"raum", "dose")
                #ds2 = CSV5.objects.values_list("switch_ip", "switch_port")
                #print("ds1: ", ds1)
                print("count: ", count)
                print("dataset1: ", dataset1)
                print("dataset2: ", dataset2)
                print("dataset1: ", dataset1.exists())
                print("dataset2: ", dataset2.exists())
                print("save: ", save)

                if (dataset1.exists() and not dataset2.exists()):
                    #instance = get_object_or_404(CSV5, id=count)
                    print("Fall 1")
                    ins = CSV5.objects.filter(gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                 gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                 raum=row[3], dose=row[4])
                    #liste.append(ins.values_list())
                    #print("liste: ", liste)
                    print ("instance: ", ins)
                    if save == True and form2.is_valid():
                        ins.update(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6], datum = row[7], akteur = row[8])
                    else:
                        updated_list.append(ins)
                    updated_obj += 1
                elif not dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists():
                    print("Fall 2")
                    ins = CSV5.objects.filter(switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6])
                    print("instance: ", ins)
                    if save == True and form2.is_valid():
                        ins.update(gebaeudebereich = row[0], gebaeudenummer = row[1], ebene = row[2], raum = row[3],
                                   dose = row[4], datum = row[7], akteur = row[8])
                    else:
                        updated_list.append(ins.values_list())
                        print("dat2: ", dataset2)
                    updated_obj += 1
                elif (dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists()):
                    print("Fall 3")
                    #liste.append(dataset1)
                    #print("liste: ", liste)
                    duplicate_obj += 1
                elif not (dataset1.exists() and dataset2.exists()):
                    print("Fall 4")
                    if save == True and form2.is_valid():
                        ins = CSV5.objects.get_or_create(id=CSV5.objects.count() + 1, gebaeudebereich=row[0],
                                                     gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2],
                                                     raum=row[3], dose=row[4], switch_ip=row[5], switch_port=row[6],
                                                     datum=row[7], akteur=row[8])
                        created_list.append(ins)
                        ins.save()
                    created_obj += 1
            except IndexError:
                print("IndexError")
                break
            except IntegrityError:
                duplicate_obj += 1
                print("IntegrityError")

        if save == False:
            messages.success(request, "Einträge die neu hinzugefügt werden: %s " % created_obj)
            messages.success(request, "Einträge die überschrieben werden: %s " % updated_obj)
            messages.success(request, "Duplikate: %s " % duplicate_obj)

        elif save == True:
            messages.success(request, "Objects created: %s" % created_obj)
            messages.success(request, "Objects updated: %s " % updated_obj)
            messages.success(request, "Duplicate Objects: %s " % duplicate_obj)
            return redirect('appp:index')


        form2 = ConfirmationForm()
        return render(request, "appp/confirmation.html", {'form' : form2})


    form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
        request, "appp/file_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```

This is a helper function that caches the file:

```
def get_data(request,save):
    data = cache.get('cached_file')
    if save:
        data = cache.get('cached_file')
        cache.set('save', False,timeout=1200)
    else:
        data = request.FILES['file']
        print("dt: ", data)
        cache.set('cached_file', data, 1200)
        cache.set('save',True, 1200)
    return data
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is unclear. How would the form be submitted if the submit button had not been clicked? (Also, that's far too much code.)

Comment: Sorry for the huge amount of code. The answer from @iakovos solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On template html file

```html
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <input type="submit" value="YourValue" name="NameOfYourButton"/>
</form>
```

In your views.py file

```py
if request.GET.get('NameOfYourButton') == 'YourValue':
    print('user clicked button')
```